# What web language to use to create slidshows on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a website that has slides on the home page. For example when you open a website you will see that users can slide through different images using those tiny dots below the images or sometimes they are timed and the slides move on their own. I want to know what web language I need to use to create this effect? Are there any tutorials that explains how to achieve this effect? I have only learnt HTML5 and still learning css3. Thanks.

Comment: You tagged it with the language needed.

Comment: *Note* Stack Overflow is not the site for tutorial recommendations. So this is an off-topic question.

Comment: You can do it in either css or js or both. But in either way , html would be required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll most likely need JavaScript to get what you are looking for.

I usually like to recommend the jQuery Cycle2 Plugin for these cases, as it's easy to use and very straightforward:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea about plugins...

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple slider in case you need to get started quickly:

http://www.basic-slider.com/